# specifying data bind attributes in twitterbootstrap.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using knockout js and twitter-bootstrap.mvc4....

I am not able to combine those two to specify the customer data binding attributes

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-bind", "value: SupplierName" } })
```

but how to do it in bootstrap

```
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor( m=> m.Id).... ????
```

the textboxfor in bootstrap takes just one parameter. is there any other way to specify it?

Comment: From which library have you got the `Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor`?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC/

Comment: That's not part of the official Twitter Bootstrap MVC nuget package. All the linked package is responsible for is literally dumping Bootstrap into your project. There's no C# code.

Comment: The library that provides `Html.Bootstrap()` extensions is [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TwitterBootstrapMVC/), the documentation for which is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming [this](https://twitterbootstrapmvc.codeplex.com/) is the project you're using since I can't find an exact match to "twitter-bootstrap.mvc4" or "twitterbootstrap.mvc". *(When referencing a third-party library you're using, provide a source link in case not everyone is familiar with it.)*

Looking at the source code, it does indeed only take one parameter, so basically, you're SOL. It *is* open source, though, so there's nothing stopping you from forking it and creating your own version or even contributing directly to this project (just create a new ticket and submit a patch).

FWIW, you're killing yourself with the `new Dictionary<string, object>` jazz. Just do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { data_bind = "value: SupplierName" })
```

Comment: This is just partially true: `Bootstrap().TextBoxFor` takes one arguement but returns a `BootstrapTextBox` object [see source](https://twitterbootstrapmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TwitterBootstrapMVC/Controls/BootstrapTextBox.cs) which has a `HtmlAttributes` method...

Comment: you both are right.. thanks a lot for helping... i got the correct answer by mixing answers from both... `@Html.Bootstrap().TextBox("Id :").HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind="value: Id"})`